# How to count how many times a word in a list appeared in-another list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, count, sum

I have 2 lists and I want to see how many of the text in list 1 is in list 2 but I don't really know of a way to like combine them the output isn't summed and I have tried sum method but it does it for all words counted not each word.

Code:

```py
l1 = ['hello', 'hi']
l2 = ['hey', 'hi', 'hello', 'hello']
for i in l2:
    print(f'{l1.count(i)}: {i}')
```

Output:

```py
0: hey
1: hi
1: hello
1: hello
```

What I want is something more like this:

```py
0: hey
1: hi
2: hello
```

Comment: First create the code to count how many times a single word is in a list. Once you have that correct, you build on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple fix is to just flip the way you are looping through the lists:

```
l1 = ['hello', 'hi']
l2 = ['hey', 'hi', 'hello', 'hello']
for i in l1:
    print(f'{l2.count(i)}: {i}')
```

Output:

```
2: hello
1: hi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from collections import Counter

l1 = ['hello', 'hi']
l2 = ['hey', 'hi', 'hello', 'hello']

c = Counter(l2)


for a in l1:
    print(f"{c[a]}: {a}")
    c.pop(a)

print(*["0: " + a for a in c.keys()], sep='\n')
```

OUTPUT

```
2: hello
1: hi
0: hey
```